# Filtering in 3D space with CUDA, horizontal access faster than vertical access?

Tags: image-processing, 3d, cuda, stereo-3d, imagefilter

I'm trying to apply filter 1x3, 3x1 repectively in 3D-structure(volume).
For example, if there is 20(cols) x 10(rows) x 10(depth) structure,

```
for(int depth = 0; depth < 10; depth++)
    Apply image filter(depth);
```

Apply filter to 2d image(20x10) 10 times. every slice of image is different.

first, i allocate 3D structure like

```
// COLS = 450, ROWS = 375, MAX_DISPARITY = 60
cudaPitchedPtr volume;
cudaExtent volumeExtent = make_cudaExtent(COLS, ROWS, MAX_DISPARITY);
HANDLE_ERROR(cudaMalloc3D(&volume, volumeExtent ));
```

and memory set to zero for stable output.
so far so good, until copy image into volume.

when applying 3x1 filter like below, it's computation time was 6 mSec.

```
Apply_3by1 << <ROWS, COLS, COLS>> > (volume, COLS, ROWS);

__global__ void Apply_3by1 (cudaPitchedPtr src, unsigned int COLS, unsigned int ROWS)
{
    const unsigned int x = threadIdx.x;
    const unsigned int y = blockIdx.x;

    extern __shared__ unsigned char SharedMemory[];
    for (int dispCnt = 0; dispCnt < MAX_DISPARITY; dispCnt++)
    {
        if (x < dispCnt) continue;//exception for my algorithm.

        unsigned char dst_val = *GET_UCHAR_PTR_3D(src, x, y, dispCnt);
        SharedMemory[x] = dst_val;
        __syncthreads();


        unsigned char left;
        int leftIdx = x - 3;
        if (leftIdx < 0)//index underflow
            left = 0;
        else
            left = SharedMemory[leftIdx];


        unsigned char right;//index overflow
        int rightIdx = x + 3;
        if (COLS < rightIdx)
            right = 0;
        else
            right = SharedMemory[rightIdx];


        *GET_UCHAR_PTR_3D(src, x, y, dispCnt) += left + right;
    }
}
```

but when i apply vertical direction 1x3 filter, it's computation time was 46mSec.

```
  Apply_1by3 << <COLS, ROWS, ROWS >> > (volume, COLS, ROWS);

__global__ void Apply_1by3 (cudaPitchedPtr src, unsigned int COLS, unsigned int ROWS)
{
    const unsigned int x = threadIdx.x;
    const unsigned int y = blockIdx.x;

    extern __shared__ unsigned char SharedMemory[];
    for (int dispCnt = 0; dispCnt < MAX_DISPARITY; dispCnt++)
    {
        unsigned char my_val = *GET_UCHAR_PTR_3D(src, y, x, dispCnt);
        SharedMemory[x] = my_val;
        __syncthreads();

        if (y < dispCnt) continue;

        int topIdx = x - 3;
        unsigned char top_value;
        if (topIdx < 0)
            top_value = 0;
        else
            top_value = SharedMemory[topIdx];

        int bottomIdx = x + 3;
        unsigned char bottom_value;
        if (ROWS <= bottomIdx)
            bottom_value = 0;
        else
            bottom_value = SharedMemory[bottomIdx];

        *GET_UCHAR_PTR_3D(src, y, x, dispCnt) += bottom_value + top_value;
    }
}
```

I have no idea why vertical direction access is slower than horizontal access, almost 8 times. if you know why it's access time is different, please enlighten me.

My apology, i forgot to add

```
#define GET_UCHAR_PTR_3D(pptr, x, y, d) \
(unsigned char*)((char*)(pptr).ptr + (sizeof(unsigned char)* x) + ((pptr).pitch * y) + ((pptr).pitch * (pptr).ysize * d))
```

Comment: Horizontal access might be coalescing nicely, whereas vertical access might not.  That's just a guess, not knowing what `GET_UCHAR_PTR_3D` does.    You need to provide a *complete code*, i.e. an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the difference.  That is something that someone can copy, paste, compile, and run, and see the issue, without having to add anything or change anything.  Voting to close.

Comment: Thanks, It's my bad. i edit what GET_UCHAR_PTR_3D is . I'll describe my code detail as i can soon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the global memory accessing and coalescing behavior between the two cases.  It does not matter whether we consider the load operation:

```
    unsigned char my_val = *GET_UCHAR_PTR_3D(src, y, x, dispCnt);
```

or the store operation:

```
    *GET_UCHAR_PTR_3D(src, y, x, dispCnt) += bottom_value + top_value;
```

Let's unpack your macro and substitute in the actual values of `x`, and `y` in each case:

```
define GET_UCHAR_PTR_3D(pptr, x, y, d) \
(unsigned char*)((char*)(pptr).ptr + (sizeof(unsigned char)* x) + ((pptr).pitch * y) + ((pptr).pitch * (pptr).ysize * d))
```

we have:

```
  (a pointer) + (1*x) + (pitch*y) + offset
```

Now, if x = threadIdx.x and y = blockIdx.x we have:

```
  (a pointer) + (1*threadIdx.x) + (pitch*blockIdx.x) + offset
```

which becomes:

```
  (a pointer) + (some offset) + threadIdx.x
```

and this will nicely coalesce.  Adjacent threads in a warp will read adjacent locations in memory.  This is the "good case".

Now what happens if x = blockIdx.x and y = threadIdx.x?  we have:

```
  (a pointer) + (1*blockIdx.x) + (pitch*threadIdx.x) + offset
```

which becomes:

```
  (a pointer) + (some offset) + (pitch*threadIdx.x)
```

This means that adjacent threads in a warp are *not* reading adjacent locations in memory, but instead are reading locations that are separated by the `pitch` value.  This will *not* coalesce, and will translate into many more global requests to satisfy the warp activity.  This is the "bad case".

GPUs like "horizontal" memory access in a warp.  They dislike "vertical" memory access within a warp.  This will result in a very substantial performance difference between the two cases.  It's not uncommon to see a 10x perf difference between these two cases, and theoretically it could be as high as a 32x perf difference.

If you'd like more background on optimization for coalesced global memory access, try [this](http://on-demand.gputechconf.com/gtc/2012/presentations/S0514-GTC2012-GPU-Performance-Analysis.pdf) presentation, especially slides 30-48.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. you are genious. I'm very happy with your comment. as i understand with your linked, warp scheduler allocate address for kernel threads. In case of horizontal access, it's situation is like page 36~39. while vertical access is going wrong like page 45. you enlighten me, thank you.